# Why is our ASP.NET 2.0 intranet app very slow after changeover from ASP.NET 1.1?

Tags: asp.net

We thought our ASP.NET 1.1 intranet app was slow, so we upgraded from 1.1 to 2.0 and the app died:

a) moved all reports onto a seperate database

b) we upgraded SQL server 2005 to a brand new server and SQL 2008 R2

c) we can see the database load is very light and it idles, so the bottleneck is not on SQL Server.

d) Deployed the application in Release mode (not in Debugging mode).

e) Network is running at 2%

f) 2 Servers are physical, not a VM.

g) Fast ping, same as it was for 1.1 version < 1ms response time.

To sum up - our database is lightling fast and the app is painfully slow.

I have checked the previous questions, none of them seem to apply here. I've googled it & cannot find anything useful. Does anybody have any ideas what are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the routines which takes the time.

Maybe enabling [ASP.NET Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx) is a good point to start.

Another possibility is to use a .NET profiler. Or you can simple add some logging into a textfile with timestamps to your app to find the slowly running code.